# Conditional expected value?

Tags: probability

> A player draws balls one after another from a box with 5 red balls and 4 black balls. For each red ball the player gets $2$ coins. For each black ball the player loses $1$ coin. Let $X$ be the random variable that tells the player's money. Let $Y$ be a random variable that takes the value $1$ if the first ball is red, and $0$ if the first ball is black. Compute $\mathbb E(X|Y=1)$.
>    a) $\frac{4}{3}$. b) $\frac{1}{2}$, c) $\frac{5}{2}$, d) $-\frac{2}{7}$, e)$-\frac{1}{8}$.

This was a question from an exam I took today. To me the question is wrong because it doesn't say where to stop drawing balls. If we "draw balls one after another" we end up with the $9$ balls, this will give us $X=6$, independent from what value $Y$ takes.

Do you think the question is wrong as well? I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I would guess you stop drawing balls after you lose all of your coins, but you're right, it's not very well specified.

Comment: Maybe it's a trick (or aptitude) question where you are being checked for your ability to realize that X will have an independent value of 6. Most people will try figuring out a probability.

Comment: @user45195 yes, it could be. However the answer is not in the options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the question makes no sense in this form. Most likely the word "two" is missing in "draws balls", and drawing without replacement is meant to be implied. Under that (re)interpretation, the answer is c).